# can not found GlideApp

Tags: android, android-glide

in app/build.gradle:

```
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    implementation 'com.github.qoqa:glide-svg:2.0.4'
```

in adapter

```
    GlideApp.with(this)
            .load(serivceURL)
            .into(picto_view);
```

But compile error:

```
Can't resolve GlideApp
```

Answer (score 0):

This [library](https://github.com/qoqa/glide-svg) is a Glide extension for SVG and **works with** [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

There is not info in the repo but you have to add in your [dependencies also](https://github.com/qoqa/glide-svg/blob/master/sample/build.gradle#L33):

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
}
```

Comment: Not help. Project build and run but remote svg file not show

Comment: @a_subscriber ok, but it seems a different issue. Your question is about: *compile error: Can't resolve GlideApp*.

Comment: I found solution: This lib success show remote svg: https://github.com/corouteam/GlideToVectorYou

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the GlideApp you have to create the GlideAppModule,

Just create a class like

```
@GlideModule public final class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule { // leave empty for now }
```

After that, make projekt, and it should go.
 Also as @Gabriel Mariotti stated, add the mentioned dependencies to gradle

```
dependencies { implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0' annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0' }
```

Comment: Not help. Project build and run but remote svg file not show.

Comment: Well, your reported issue was not related to the showing of svg, it was bout the compile error.

Comment: I found solution: This lib success show remote svg: https://github.com/corouteam/GlideToVectorYou